# Timer intervals getting mixed up between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am using System.Timers on a multithreaded application in .net 2.0 with C#.
Each thread is supposed to set a different time interval for its timer elapsed event.

Here's my scenario:

I have a root folder say: D://ThreadingDemo/Clients. Now the Clients folder can contain n number of folders. Let's say : 1 and 2 (in actual scenario equal to number of clients). In each folder there is an xml configuration file (having client specific details).

*Config for 1:*

ApplicationName: Application Support for Client 1

ClientCode: A

TimeInterval: 5000

*Config for 2:*

ApplicationName: Application Support for Client 2

ClientCode: B

TimeInterval: 2000

Now my application creates thread as many as the number of clients. In this case, 2 threads and sets a time interval within the thread.
Thread 1 with an interval of 5000 millisec and Thread 2 with 2000ms

below is the code I work on:

namespace ConsoleApplication3

{

```
class Program

{

    static string location = "D:\\ThreadingDemo\\Clients\\";
    public static System.Timers.Timer emailTriggerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    static Double timeinterval;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(location);
        Thread th;
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            th = new Thread(() => DoWork(g.Name)); //** Passes CLIENT NAME to the method
            th.Name = g.Name;
            th.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" ThreadStart - ClientName : " + g.Name + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoWork(string fname)
    {

        emailTriggerTimer.Interval = GetsExecutionTimeFromConfigFile(); //** Gets Client specific FIRST EXECUTION TIME and converts to Time Interval
        emailTriggerTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(sender, e, fname));
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = true;
        emailTriggerTimer.AutoReset = true;
        emailTriggerTimer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(" DoWork - ClientName :" + fname + " " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private static object emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, string fname)
    {
        emailTriggerTimer.Stop();
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = false;

        Console.WriteLine(fname + " Elapsed "   + DateTime.Now);
        emailTriggerTimer.Interval = GetsTimeIntervalFromConfigFile(); //** Gets Client specific TIME INTERVAL

        emailTriggerTimer.Start();
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

}

My code is definitely screwing up the timer intervals and setting the last timer interval on both the threads ie 2000ms and here's the output below:

ThreadStart - ClientName :1 27/06/2013 12:13:12

ThreadStart - ClientName :2 27/06/2013 12:13:12

DoWork - ClientName :1 27/06/2013 12:13:12

DoWork - ClientName :2 27/06/2013 12:13:12

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:13

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:13

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:15

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:15

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:17

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:17

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:19

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:19

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:21

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:21

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:23

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 12:13:23

I am pretty new to threading concepts using timer. I would appreciate if someone suggest how to set timer interval for elapses in each thread separately. Thanks!

Comment: You are using the same timer for all threads!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But the time intervals still not proper in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me. I revisited this with a simple change. The first execution was not set by the timer but was done by allowing the thread to sleep. The interval set for the timers (after 1st execution) worked perfectly. Here's the  code:

class Program

```
{

    static string location = "D:\\ThreadingDemo\\Clients\\";
    static Double timeinterval;
    public static System.Timers.Timer emailTriggerTimer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(location);
        Thread th;
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            th = new Thread(() => DoWork(g.Name));
            th.Name = g.Name;
            th.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" ThreadStart - ClientName :" + g.Name + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoWork(string fname)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(GetsExecutionTimeFromConfigFile()));//** Gets Client specific FIRST EXECUTION TIME and converts to Time Interval           

        emailTriggerTimer  = new System.Timers.Timer();
        emailTriggerTimer.AutoReset = true;
        emailTriggerTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(sender, e, fname));
        emailTriggerTimer.Interval =  GetsTimeIntervalFromConfigFile(); //** Gets Client specific TIME INTERVAL
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = true;

        emailTriggerTimer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(" DoWork - ClientName :" + fname + " " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private static void emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, string fname)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ClientName : " + fname + " Elapsed " + " " + DateTime.Now );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a single timer object for all threads, the eventhandlers of each thread is added to that single timer. Therefore, when the interval of that single timer object expires, all eventhandlers are executed.

The solution is to create a timer object for each individual thread.

Something like this.

```
class Program {
    static string location = "D:\\ThreadingDemo\\Clients\\";
    static Double timeinterval;


    static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(location);
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in dir.GetDirectories()) {
            var th = new Thread(() => DoWork(g.Name)); //** Passes CLIENT NAME to the method
            th.Name = g.Name;
            th.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" ThreadStart - ClientName : " + g.Name + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoWork(string fname) {
        var emailTriggerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        emailTriggerTimer.Interval = GetsExecutionTimeFromConfigFile(); //** Gets Client specific FIRST EXECUTION TIME and converts to Time Interval
        emailTriggerTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(sender, e, fname, emailTriggerTimer));
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = true;
        emailTriggerTimer.AutoReset = true;
        emailTriggerTimer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(" DoWork - ClientName :" + fname + " " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private static void emailTriggerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, string fname, System.Timers.Timer emailTriggerTimer) {
        emailTriggerTimer.Stop();
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = false;

        Console.WriteLine(fname + " Elapsed "   + DateTime.Now);
        emailTriggerTimer.Interval = GetsTimeIntervalFromConfigFile(); //** Gets Client specific TIME INTERVAL

        emailTriggerTimer.Start();
        emailTriggerTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st thread seems to work at 5 sec interval. But the 2nd thread works at 2 sec interval (as it should) not always

ThreadStart - ClientName :1 27/06/2013 13:40:11

 ThreadStart - ClientName :2 27/06/2013 13:40:11

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:13

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:15

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:16

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:21 //** here it is 5 sec

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:21

ClientName : 1 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:26

ClientName : 2 Elapsed  27/06/2013 13:40:31 //** here it is 10 sec

Comment: Check the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx. Since the Elapsed-event is pushed to the threadpool, the exact execution time can vary.